# Authentification to Google Drive API with OAuth from Google Apps For Business possible?

Tags: google-drive-api

I use Google Apps For Business to manage 14 accounts for a domain.

There is the possibility to set a OAuth key and secret for the domain. With this credentials you can access all files from each account without knowing their personal password or oauth credentials.

With the Google Documents List API it was easy to write a small script so that i could back up the data.

Is it possible to back up these files with the new Google Drive Api without knowing each OAuth2 credential?

Answer (score 4):

there is a notion of Service Accounts by which you can reach what you want, have a look at google's docs on this https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation